# Delete multiple users from TestFlight

Tags: ios, testflight

While going through my Team List, I noticed that the only way to delete / remove users from my team was to go one by one. Is there a faster way to do this?

On selecting a user, the available actions do not have REMOVE.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I did. This is stupid, but it worked.

```
emails = [
  "test@example.com",
  "foo@example.com",
  "bar@example.com"
]

emails.each do |email|
  `open https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/ra/ng/users_roles/#{email}/testerDetails`
end
```

This Ruby script will open up a browser for each email you supply, pre-loaded to the page that has the user delete button. Then if you resize your browser window, you can get it so the delete button lines up closely with the confirmation button, then click delete, click confirm and switch to the next tab (using the keyboard shortcut to do it faster).

I told you it was stupid!